# Как организовать запрос root прав при сохранении файла qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

У меня есть приложение, писаное на qt5, которому могут понадобиться root права при сохранении файла. То есть пользователь сам выбирает в QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(), куда ему сохранять. И если выберет что-то типа в /etc, то ему могут потребоваться root права.

Так вот, как это организовать? То есть запрос root прав должен происходить именно тогда, когда пользователь выберет путь сохранения, по которому без рута нельзя. Кто что посоветует? Есть ли какие-нибудь готовые механизмы для этого?

Comment: Проще всего дать этому приложению (исполнимому файлу, конечно, а не какому-либо интерпретируемому скрипту) бит `-s` и owner root (но тщательно просчитайте все последствия, мы же не знаем, что именно может в принципе Ваше приложение натворить).

Answer (score 3):

Мои пять копеек.

При помощи QFileInfo проверяется доступность записи (или вообще доступа) при помощи ::permission() или isWritable() или смотреть документацию.

Дальше, действительно, вызываем стороннее приложение через su/sudo. Варианта два:

1. Сохраняем файл во временное хранилище (/tmp/XXXX) и при помощи `sudo
   cp` скопировать. Для чтения, если не хватает прав, аналогично, но в
   обратном порядке. Нужно не забывать об исходных правах на доступ и
   восстановить их потом.
2. Аналогично, но используем `sudo cat` и `sudo
   tee` для чтения и записи используя стандартные потоки ввода и
   вывода. В данном случае промежуточные файлы не потребуются, но нужно
   будет плотнее заморочиться с чтением/записью в канал процесса.

В обоих случаях нужно читать стандартные поток ошибок и при появлении запроса на ввод пароля вывести диалоговое окно с запросом оного и передать его в stdin процесса + '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша программа должна изначально запущена в режиме повышенных привилегий (root), то есть она должна быть запущена от пользователя, который имеет доступ к нужной вам директории.
Если это не так, то невозможно получить доступ к файлам, потому что операционная система не позволит это сделать. Вы должны выполнить свою программу с использованием sudo.
Для получения сведений о правах доступа к файлу, вы можете использовать `QFile::permissions()`

Comment: нет, такой вариант не подходит. А приложения, которые запрашивают root права во время работы есть.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант. Вы можете запустить дочерний процесс от имени суперпользователя, соединиться с ним через пайп и получить таким способом доступ к нужному файлу.

Comment: а что вы думаете насчёт использования polkit?

Comment: @zamazan4ik технически, этот глюкодром реализует то, что я описал. Только сложным способом с кучей дурацких наворотов и привлечением D-Bus. Энтузиаст на букву П, догадавшийся засунуть чисто юзерспейсное явление (dbus) в сердце ОС должен сидеть на раскаленной сковородке без конфет. Так считаю.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял вас. То есть мне стоит написать приложение-комбайн, которое я буду вызывать при каждом действии, которое может требовать root прав, вызывая его с рут-правами оно будет выполнять все эти действия?